# not able to subscribe dynamic topic. using aws-iot-device-sdk

Tags: node.js, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

**when I subscribe dynamic topic for connecting shadow. I m not able to establish connect the device. with out subscribe it's connected but not able to receive message payload.**

Code

```
this.thingShadows = new awsiot.thingShadow({
  keyPath: keyPath,
  certPath: certPath,
  caPath: caPath,
  clientId: clientId, //"sdk-nodejs-" + clientId,
  host: host,
  debug: true,
});

this.thingShadows.subscribe(clientId + "/*");
```

Policy

```
 {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "iot:Connect"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:453533943651:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
  ]
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "iot:Publish"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iot:us-south-1:453533943651:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
  ]
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "iot:Subscribe"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iot:us-south-1:453533943651:topicfilter/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
  ]
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "iot:Receive"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:453533943651:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
  ]
}
```

Logs/Output

error Error: premature close
at onclosenexttick (/Users/murtuzanalawala/Node/RiooNode/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:54:86)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
connection lost - will attempt reconnection in 128 seconds...
close
reconnect/re-register
connect
offline

Thanks in advance for your good suggestion.

[Github Question](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/353)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can't able to subscribe dynamic topic you have to change the policy "arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:453533943651:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*" to *..for allow all device.then you can subscribe.topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName} this denotes the thingname should be come end of the topic. change to allow all you will able to subscribe.